# gcc won't compile simple C program on Interix- Windows 7 x64

Tags: c, interix

I just set up Interix on my new workstation here at the lab. Originally, I was just going to set up the x64 tools (you know, the ones from Interop), but when I did that, some things didn't work. Then I went ahead and installed the x86 tools. I'm *assuming* the 32-bit tools are getting used.

I went ahead and transferred over a file I was working on with Interix on an x86 machine. Basic C program, nothing fancy. Just something we're working on in class. I can open it using NEdit and Vim and the like, but it won't compile, no matter what shell I issue the gcc command in. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

As I'm relatively new to POSIX-compliant systems, I'm not sure how to fix this. Can one of you fine individuals tell me how to fix this in layman's terms?

EDIT:

If you're looking to do UNIX work on Windows... just use Cygwin. I'm editing this to tell you this because you are probably lost and looking up answers on Google. Windows 8 removed Interix anyways.

Comment: any particular reason to use interix?  mingw seems much more sane